# Should Windows 7's built-in image restore really be so slow that it takes DAYS?

Tags: windows, data-recovery, restore

When I restore a ~500 GB disk image made with Windows 7's built-in system image tool, it runs for 8-10 hours with very little progress, and even after 3 days it is still only about 30% done.

Why is this happening, and what can I do to fix it?

---

**Background/original version of question**

I've been using Windows 7's built-in backup program to back up my 1 TB boot hard disk to another 2 TB internal disk drive, choosing to create a boot-drive system image along the way. I've tested the backup drive by occasionally restoring a few files from backup and manually verifying the contents, but never had the chance to try restoring the image. The last such manual test was a few weeks ago.

My system started acting up in the past few days, so I decided about 12 hours ago to restore from the latest image, created last Sunday. So, I booted from a Windows 7 install disc and chose to "Recover from the system image" instead of installing. I kicked off the recovery with the default options, and then I went out for the day. With the ~500 GB of used space on the boot drive, I figured it would be a full 8-12 hours before the recovery completed.

9 hours later, I came back, and not only is the recovery not done, the progress meter has barely budged from the start. Maybe 3-5% progress at most, although there is no percentage or estimated time remaining, so I can't tell whether it's just going very slowly or if it's hanged altogether. Assuming the latter, I've decided to just cancel the recovery (and by "cancel", I mean hard-reset the machine) and reformat the boot drive altogether before trying the restoration again.

So, here's my question: is it really to be expected that, with ~500 GB of data to restore, that it would really take days to restore the system image? And if not, what could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, I have the chipset's* SATA controller set to AHCI mode instead of PATA/IDE emulation mode in the BIOS setup. Other people have found that [switching the SATA controller from AHCI mode to IDE mode in the BIOS suddenly makes the image restore go much, much faster.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/image-restore-using-windows-7-ultimate-edition/7a4958f8-34c4-4f5a-be27-e9312ef75f80)^ I tried this, and lo and behold, the restore finished in less than two hours and booted to a working system.

Although my chipset is made by Intel, this is not an Intel-specific problem: a Google search for [*windows 7 image restore slow ahci*](http://www.google.com/search?q=windows+7+image+restore+slow+ahci) leads to [this video which shows the same solution on an AMD box.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpMWHlx8r1s)

---

* The motherboard is a [Gigabyte EP45T-USB3P](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3329&dl=1), which has an [Intel P45 chipset](http://ark.intel.com/products/chipsets/34470) with an [ICH10R southbridge](http://ark.intel.com/products/34395/Intel-82801JR-IO-Controller)/SATA controller.

^ At first, when I suspected AHCI mode was the problem, I tried downloading [the latest AHCI driver from Intel](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=20625&ProdId=2973&lang=eng&OSVersion=Windows%207%20%2864-bit%29*&DownloadType=Drivers) and loading it into the Windows 7 recovery environment. In my case, the driver installation failed, but installing the driver may well work for you.